# Limit $\lim _{x \to 0}\sqrt {x+\sqrt {x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x...}}}}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I've been investigating some interesting infinite square roots, and I've arrived at the hypothesis that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt {x+\sqrt {x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x...}}}}=1$$
However, I have tried to prove this but have found myself unable to do so. For example, I've tried re-writing this as $$1=\sqrt{x+1}$$ so $1=x+1$, which leads us to $x=0$, which doesn't exactly work- replacing $x$ with $0$ yields a value of $0$.

That's another side point: obviously the method I just used yields an incorrect result, but where is the maths flawed?

Please could you either prove or disprove my hypothesis? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: if $y = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}+\ldots}}$, then $y=\sqrt{x+y}$, or $y^2=x+y$; you can solve this quadratic to find an explicit expression, and then find the limit as $x\to0^+$.

Comment: Thanks for that! I have done that beforehand, but this either results in $0$ or $1$. Which value do I choose?

Comment: When $x>0$ you have to choose the $+$ sign, since obviously y$>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying @saulspatz, that makes a lot more sense now :)

Comment: @A-levelStudent You have to be cautious with the kind of algebraic manipulation given in comments and ansewrs. For example, applying it to $\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{x^6}+\cdots\right)$ we obtain $y=1+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{x^6}+\cdots$. Then, $y=1+\frac{1}{x^2}y$ and thus $y=\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}$. Therefore $\lim\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}+\cdots\right)=\lim\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}=0$, which makes no sense because the limit should be $\geq 1$. So, you need to understand not only the algebraic manipulation, but also the reason why it works (or not).

Comment: I see, thanks for bringing that to my attention. Could you explain when the manipulation works then and when it doesn't?

Comment: @A-levelStudent If you write something like $y = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}+\ldots}}$ or $y=1+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{x^6}+\cdots$, then you are assuming that the right-hand side converges or, in other words, that $y$ is indeed a real number. So, you are allowed to manipulate the equality provided that you already know that the right-hand side converges. Otherwise, the first step is to prove convergence. In your problem it converges. In my example, it doesn't (if $x$ is small).

Comment: I understand now, thanks a lot for helping me! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $a_0 = \sqrt{x}$ and $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{x+a_n}$. We need to show that

$1$. $a_{n+1} > a_n$ (the sequence is monotonically increasing)

$2$. There exists an $m$ such that $a_n \leq m$ for all $n$ (the sequence is bounded)

$1$ is easy. We have $a_0 = \sqrt{x}$ and $a_1 = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}$. First, $a_1 > a_0$ as we have
$$\sqrt{x} > 0 \iff x+\sqrt{x} > x \iff \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}>\sqrt{x} \iff a_1 > a_0$$
Assume $1$ holds up to $n$. Then $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{x+a_n} > \sqrt{x+a_{n-1}} = a_n$ so $1$ holds for $a_{n+1}$. By induction, $1$ holds such that $a_n$ is monotonically increasing.

Now for $2$, we do the following. You can use the common way to solve this kind of radical, which is to assign a value to it $y$:
$$y = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\ldots}}}}$$
$$y^2 = x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\ldots}}$$
$$y^2=x+y$$
$$y^2-y-x=0$$
Using the quadratic equation,
$$y=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$$
$y > 0$ so the smaller solution is extraneous.
$$y = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$$
this means
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$$
and we can prove the bound
$$a_n \leq \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2} $$
inductively. First, we have $a_0 = \sqrt{x} < \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+x} = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$. Now assume the inequality is true for all $a_i$ for $i \leq n$. Then, for $x\geq 0$,
$$\Big(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}\Big)^2 = \frac{1+2\sqrt{1+4x}+(1+4x)}{4} = x + \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$$
so
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2} = \sqrt{x+\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}}$$
Then
$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{x+a_n} \leq \sqrt{x+\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}} = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$$
Therefore, this sequence is bounded and monotonically increasing, so it converges. Now we can evaluate: at $0$, it comes out to
$$y\vert_0=\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\ldots}}}}= \frac{1+
\sqrt{1}}{2}=1$$

Comment: You don't need a "rule of thumb".  Taking the minus sign would give $y<0$ which is clearly impossible.

Comment: yes sorry I will change that @saulspatz

Comment: There is more to be done here.  You proved: **if** the iterated radical converges, **then** the limit is as  you found.  But in addition, you need to show that it converges.

Comment: @RyanShesler are we not assuming that it is convergent already? At the very least, we have to show that it is bounded first

Comment: and you @GEdgar sorry it wouldn't let me tag more than one person

Comment: ? @crystal_math I did not use the fact $y=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\ldots}}$ in my proof that the sequence $a_n$ is bounded for $x \geq 0$. I simply provided the motivation for the bound and then showed that for fixed real $x \geq 0$ the sequence is bounded by a real number. Taking the square root of $a_n$ for arbitrary finite $n$ is always defined for $x \geq 0$ as it itself is not an infinitely nested radical.

Comment: Some of the recursions have $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{x+\sqrt a_n}$ instead of $\sqrt{x+a_n}$. (I've posted an alternative that uses a simpler upper bound for the sequence.)

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative to Ryan Shesler's answer, differing mainly in the upper bound that establishes that the limit exists.

Let $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x+x_n}$, with $x\gt0$. Then $x_n$ is an increasing sequence since $x_1=\sqrt x\gt0=x_0$ and $x_n\gt x_{n-1}$ implies $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x+x_n}\gt\sqrt{x+x_{n-1}}=x_n$, and $x_n$ is bounded above by $1+x$ since $x_0=0$ is certainly less than $1+x$ and if $x_n\lt1+x$ then $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x+x_n}\lt\sqrt{x+(1+x)}=\sqrt{1+2x}\lt1+x$. Consequently the limit as $n\to\infty$ exists.

If $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$, then $L^2=x+L$, which solves to $L=(1\pm\sqrt{1+4x})/2$, but only the positive root is possible (since $x_n\gt0$ for all $n\gt0$). Taking the limit of $(1+\sqrt{1+4x})/2$ as $x\to0^+$ gives $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt {x+\sqrt {x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x...}}}}=y\implies  \sqrt{x+y}=y$
$$\implies y^2-y-x=0$$

Solving above quadratic equation for $y>0$, we get $$y=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$$
$$\therefore \lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt {x+\sqrt {x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x...}}}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}=1$$